# Arrays are causing me problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So. Started arrays. Yeah went as well as the loops did. And as a result, I need help.

```
    /*jshint multistr:true */
    var text = "Yo yo yo, what's / good fam. My name is / Caleb, my dude.";
    var myName = "Caleb"
    var hits = []
    for(var i = 0; i >= text.length; i++){
        if(text[i] === 'C') {
           }
            for(var j = i; i <= i + myName.length; i++){ 
                }
     }
```

That is the exact code that I have. Now, What it needs to do is search for my name within the confines of the text string. Only problem is that its saying that "It looks like your second 'for' loop isn't pushing values to the hits array. Make sure it's working properly and that myName's text appears somewhere in the text variable." This *is* a CodeAcademy project. I'm just not understanding. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for your name. Okay. What then?

Comment: Yeah, your code is incomplete. Once you find the letter 'C', you loop again, but that loop doesn't do anything.  `for(var j = i; i <= i + myName.length; i++){ addStuffToDoHere }` But yes, as mentioned below, it's also infinite, so this loop needs to be changed.

Comment: If this is for a project, I suggest not asking for an answer. To steer you in the right direction, I will suggest both the .indexOf and .split functions

Comment: Yeah. I never ask for the answers. I ask for help. If I get answers I don't understand why something works. If I get help, I can figure out when, what, and where something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have all the semicolons right. Also, add some action in case the loop gets a result!
Also, i don't think you have defined var j, did you?

Finally - if it's asking u to push some values into hits array, then use this push method:

```
hits.push();
```

To help u i'd need deeper understanding of the task itself. what did u have to do, what were u starting with?

**Edit:**

```
var myName = "Caleb"; // define myName before text so it can be used in text
 var text = "Yo yo yo, what's / good fam. My name is / "+myName+", my dude.";   // define text and use myName variable between two strings, connected with +
 var hits = [];    // define hits array
 for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {    //start loop, make sure second parameter is not infinite or it would crash your browser
        if(text[i] === 'C') {    // if found i that corresponds with 'C'
                    var letterLocation = i;    // set variable letterLocation with value of 'C' position
              hits.push(i);    // add the location number to hits array with .push method
           };
     };
 console.log(hits);    // display hits array in console
```

Here's some working code for you, just follow the task and change whatever is necessary - hope it helps.
Generally - i changed the order of variables, so that u can use myName in text, also made the for loop print out the position of letter C and push this value into the hits array. Is that what u meant?

Comment: just edited the code with explanations, let me know if it has been of any use